# Estimating the Performance of a CPU

Tags: performance, cpu, computer-science

I have a question that I just can't seem to get my head around. It's probably quite simple, but I just need some guidance in the right way. 
(Note this is a study question for my upcoming exam).

So here it is,

"For integer operations a+b, and a*b take almost identical amounts of time, for floating point (32-bit) multiplication it takes approximately 3x as long. Floating point additions and integer additions take nearly identical times. For a program that is 20% logic (which takes the same amount of time regardless), 40% additions and 40% multiplications, show how to calculate the estimated performance of changing the maths from Integer to Floating point operations on the same CPU".

What steps/formula's should I use/take in order to find the estimated performance? I'm not looking for a straight answer, just a tip or two.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a terrible exam question. If the processor in any way even *resembles* a modern processor, making any performance estimations based on that information amounts to throwing darts blindfolded after being spun around in an office chair a dozen times.

Comment: This question belongs on math.stackexchange.com because it is a question about how to calculate percentages and has nothing to do with CPUs, instructions or performance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit hard to estimate as modern CPU can/might execute certain opcodes in parallel depending on the flow.

I really like this summary of how much each operations costs on CPU

[Infographics: Operation Costs in CPU Clock Cycles](http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/)

In this post there's also a bit of explanation about each of the groups of operations.